# Ajax 422 (Unprocessable Entity) Error for User Login Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, controller

I have a login modal and I am trying to use `Ajax` to check its validation. The issue I am running into is that the build in `Controllers` read the error message instead of the credentials and I get error `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` when user inputs wrong credentials.

**Blade:**

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    initLogin($('#email').val(),$('#password').val());
});
```

**JavaScript File:**

```
function initLogin(email, password) {
    $.ajax( {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },    
        url:'loginModal',
        method:'POST',
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        },    
        success: function( bolUpdated ) {
            window.location = "/home";
        },    
        fail: function() {
            alert('Incorrect');
        }     
    });   
}
```

**Route:**

`Route::post( 'loginModal', 'Auth\LoginController@login' );`

Moving forward it is all build in `Laravel` functions which ends here:

```
public static function withMessages(array $messages)
{
    return new static(tap(ValidatorFacade::make([], []), function ($validator) use ($messages) {
        foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {
            foreach (Arr::wrap($value) as $message) {
                $validator->errors()->add($key, $message);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

`$messages` has the error message `'These credentials do not match our records.'`

When I open the console log and look at the specifics of the error, it says:

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors
:
{email: ["These credentials do not match our records."]}
message
:
"The given data was invalid."
```

I am pretty new to `Laravel` and maybe this is not the correct way to approach this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
[2018-03-12 21:58:56] local.INFO: array (
  'email' => '<name@domain.com>',
  'password' => '<pass>',
)
```

Comment: can you add the data that your javascript is sending?.  Obviously you can hide the password, but just to make sure that your app is indeed sending the data correctly

Comment: @JasonSpradlin It seems to be sending the right data. See Edit.